# Plotting regression models trained with caret package

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

As title says, I have a shiny app where I introduce datasets, split and preprocess them to then train the models and compare their result/prediction sucess.

For categorical target variables I use a confusion matrix to visually display predicted vs observed results, but when It comes to numeric target variables I got suggested to use RMSE to compare them, so the plan is to plot the observed vs predicted and also add that RMSE to the plot in some way.

For numeric variables I plan to use the LM NNET models if that changes anything.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question clear and reproducible. What did you expect to see versus what you did see when you executed the code you’re having issues with? A reproducible question includes code you've attempted, listing non-base R packages, any errors/warnings received, what type of output or outcome you’re expecting, and sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).